# Angular 2 Angular Material md-grid-list columns

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I am trying to implement the Angular 2 Angular Material md-grid-list, and in the previous version of md-grid-list in angualrjs there was an option to specify how many columns on smaller screen sizes. I do not see any documentation for this for Angular 2 md-grid-list, only the one `cols` parameter in the markup.

Here is my code:

```
   <md-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="4:3" gutterSize="4px">
      <md-grid-tile
        *ngFor="let tile of tiles"
        [colspan]="tile.cols"
        [rowspan]="tile.rows"
        [style.background-image]="'url(' + tile.background + ')'"
        class="mat-elevation-z1">
        <md-grid-tile-footer>{{tile.title}}</md-grid-tile-footer>
      </md-grid-tile>
    </md-grid-list>
```

and here is the angularjs version for md-grid-list:

```
          <md-grid-list md-cols="2" 
                          md-cols-sm="2" 
                          md-cols-md="3" 
                          md-cols-gt-md="3" 
                          md-row-height-gt-md="4:3" 
                          md-row-height="4:3" 
                          md-gutter="4px" 
                          md-gutter-gt-sm="4px"
                          style="margin: 0;">
                <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="tile in vm.tiles track by $index"
                              md-rowspan="{{tile.span.row}}"
                              md-colspan="{{tile.span.col}}"
                              md-colspan-sm="{{tile.span.colSM}}"
                              md-colspan-xs="{{tile.span.colXS}}"
                              ng-class="tile.background"
                              ng-href="tile.link"
                              class="md-whiteframe-4dp">

                </md-grid-tile>
            </md-grid-list>
```

As you can see in the angularjs version there are various other arguments such as `md-cols-sm` and `md-cols-md`. I am wondering if anyone knows the syntax for this for Angular 2 since the screen size change just compresses the grid. Any and all help is very appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: how will it work??

Comment: @Aravind I am not sure what you mean, but I need the grid list to go down to two columns when on a smaller screen size.

Comment: Hope this might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891840/responsive-design-using-md-grid-list-in-angular-2