# Angular 4: Responsive Grid List

Tags: angular, material-design

Started exploring Angular 4 last night and I was just wondering if there is a way to make the `mat-grid-list` material design component responsive as easy as how Boostrap handles it?

Anyone? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: `grid-list` is already responsive;  the height/width of each tile is dynamic based on the screen ratio.  if you want the number of cols/rows to be dynamic, that is easily controlled in CSS.

Comment: As @Claies, `mat-grid-list` is already responsive. In case you want change cols value, you can write the code to detect screen size and set column number based on that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Angular 4 just seems to resize the entire grid list and no way to react to something similar to Boostrap's col-xs-12, col-md-6, etc.

Comment: I'm looking for the "cascading": effect of columns. Angular 4 and Material 2 only shrinks them which is really weird.

Comment: [this is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44846224/8759579)
Greetings :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in pure html, you could find some html/ts solution though, [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891840/responsive-design-using-md-grid-list-in-angular-2/44846224#44846224)

If you want to achieve this only with html, take a look at [the Angular Flex Layout framework](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API) instead of mat-grid-list.