# Angular 4 mat-grid-list column responsive

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

How to make column number be equal 1 at mobile phone screen? How to make this code columns screen responsive? Thanks in advance

```
 <mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="100px">
  <mat-grid-tile colspan="1" rowspan="1">
    <button mat-button="primary">
      <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
      some text
    </button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="1" rowspan="1">
      <button mat-button="primary">
        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
        some text
      </button>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="1" rowspan="1">
      <button mat-button="primary">
        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
        some text
      </button>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: [this is the answer. Grettings: ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44846224/8759579)https://stackoverflow.com/a/44846224/8759579

Comment: Same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700651/angular-4-responsive-grid-list/47176876#47176876

Comment: Refer This link already explained what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891840/responsive-design-using-md-grid-list-in-angular-2